# Android Oreo (API 26) - Create dir in external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-8.0-oreo

I've been developing an app on nougat that creates a directory in the external storage.

I used to do it like this:

```
final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Chords/Processed Audio");
dir.mkdirs();
```

This code does not seem to work on API 26 (Android Oreo). The directory is not created.

**How can I achieve the same thing, preferably that works on all android version from API 21 to API 26?**

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "does not seem to work" means. Note that you should not use string concatenation to create file paths. Use `final File dir = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Chords"), "Processed Audio");`.

Comment: I'll try as you suggested. What I mean by "Does not work" is simply that the directory isn't created, while on Nougat it does

Comment: some logcat would be useful. What about permissions? Have you granted permission to write external storage for your application?

Comment: ok It worked simply buy changing the `File` declaration as @CommonsWare suggested. Thanks. Please write the answer and I'll accept it. I think it will be useful for other people too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no problems running your existing code on a Nexus 5X running Android 8.0. Using `adb shell ls /storage/emulated/0`, I see `Chores/`, and inside there I see `Processed Audio/`. This is for an app with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, including runtime permissions.

That being said, ideally, do not use string concatenation to create `File` objects. Instead, use:

```
final File dir = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Chords"), "Processed Audio");
```

Comment: I also had all the permissions set, I've checked multiple times. Changing to your way of declaring instead of String concatenation worked for me though. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I am using this plugin (https://github.com/JoschkaSchulz/cordova-plugin-image-resizer) in cordova app.

I am facing same issue (https://github.com/JoschkaSchulz/cordova-plugin-image-resizer/issues/42).

I see this code folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folderName); and changed as you mentioned, but still its not working.

Please let us know if you find any error in this.

Comment: @NKurapati: I suggest that you edit your GitHub issue and provide a reproducible test case along with a complete set of output (e.g., stack trace).

Comment: @CommonsWare: As i am accessing through JavaScript, I am getting "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference" message only.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have updated github issue. Its failing to create directory. Please check and let us know if you found any error. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniele, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455957/966789
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031091/966789 (Android added new permission model for Android 6.0 (Marshmallow). If your targetSdkVersion >= 23 and you are running on a Marshmallow (or later) device, you may need to enable runtime permissions. You should also read more about the runtime permissions changes. If you are using targetSdkVersion >= 24, you also must configure a FileProvider as show in this section. The example below uses com.codepath.fileprovider and should match the authorities XML tag specified)