# Oreo (WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE) Permission

Tags: android, permissions

According to ["developer.android.com"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#rmp)

```
If the app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system grants only 
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that time; however, if the app later requests 
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the system immediately grants that privilege 
without prompting the user.
```

Now, I have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and I'm requesting the DownloadManager to download a file in the Public Download folder

```
downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, mAttachmentItem.getFilename());
```

Unfortunately, I got

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/emulated/0/data/user/0/com.abc.cba/files
                                                                           at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:699)
```

I have declared both of permissions in the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Read permission is already Granted and in Runtime I'm requesting Write permission, the system doesn't prompt any message or dialog, it's always Denied(Not Granted) in "onRequestPermissionsResult"

```
public static boolean isPermissionsToAccessStorageAreGranted(Context context, Activity activity) {
    ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!PermissionUtil.checkPermissions(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
        String[] permissionsList = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
        PermissionUtil.requestPermissions(activity, permissionsList,
                PermissionUtil.REQUESTCODE_ACCESS_STORAGE);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==REQUESTCODE_ACCESS_STORAGE && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
 /* downloadFile(); */       
    }
}
```

I'm trying to grant those two permissions via ADB, it shows me an error:

```
adb shell pm grant com.abc.cba 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.abc.cbs 
has not requested permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

adb shell pm grant com.abc.cba 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't change 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. It is required by the 
application
```

Comment: You need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime.

Comment: I'm requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime, the system doesn't prompt any message or dialog, it's always Denied(Not Granted) in "onRequestPermissionsResult"

Comment: Try fully uninstalling and reinstalling your app. Also, make sure that the `<uses-permission>` elements are in the proper location (as direct children of `<manifest>`).

Comment: They are in the proper location

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/data/user/0/com.abc.cba/files` That is a very strange path. It will not exist. Please dont tell that it is equivalent with `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, mAttachmentItem.getFilename()`.

Comment: Yes Actually, com.abc.cba is the package name of the Application

Comment: `adb shell pm grant com.lookiimobile.rosyboa android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.abc.cba has not requested permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
                                                                            `adb shell pm grant com.abc.cba android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't change android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. It is required by the application`

Comment: @Soulaimen I have similar problem

Comment: @svkaka: did you tried to set  `tools:node="replace"` in the Manifest file (in uses-permission) ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Actually, It was an external problem. One of App Libs I'm using request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION with android:maxSdkVersion. So when merging with my Manifest it will remove the permission for the whole application.

The Solution is to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

You are correct in adding the permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For versions of Lollipop and higher, you need to also request the permissions at runtime. To solve this problem, I created a new method `requestAppPermission` that I call when the main activity is created. This method runs only for Lollipop and higher, and returns early otherwise:

```
private void requestAppPermissions() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return;
    }

    if (hasReadPermissions() && hasWritePermissions()) {
        return;
    }

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE); // your request code
}

private boolean hasReadPermissions() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private boolean hasWritePermissions() {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

I call this method in the activity's `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Other things
    requestAppPermissions();
}
```

On first load, this will prompt the user to accept permissions.

Then, before you run any code that needs to read and write to storage, you can check these permissions, either by storing the values or running those checks again using methods `hasReadPermissions()` and `hasWritePermissions()` defined above.

Comment: _"For versions of Lollipop and higher, you need to also request the permissions at runtime"_ Nope. The runtime permission model was introduced in Marshmallow (API 23), not in Lollipop.

Answer (score 5):

You have to grant permissions at runtime on **Marshmallow** or higher.
Sample snippet :

`private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (!hasPermission) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                        },
                        REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
            }else{ startMainActivity(); }
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

For Oreo,

you need to explicitly do a READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE request (by code) even if you have already requested and is granted the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and vis versa.

prior to this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is automatically granted when WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is granted.

so what you need to do, is to

1) ask for **WRITE** permission in your codes.

2) when user grants the **WRITE** permission, ask again for **READ** permission  - this will be automatically granted (you will get an exception if you do not ask for a **READ** explicitly)

The changes for Oreo doesn't make much sense to me (no idea why do we need to ask for a permission that is automatically granted), but that is what it is.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#rmp

Comment: when I ask for WRITE first I always get -1

Comment: @svkaka, I think the general idea is to ask for permission only when you need it (e.g. prompt for camera/write permission only when user clicks the "take picture" button), rather than asking immediately when the user opens the app.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135423/11703772) for a better solution

---

### **EDIT:** This is not a solution, just a quick workaround.

If you get **permission denied** error even when the permissions are granted and you already implemented permission checks,

### make sure you're not targetting api level 29:

Change *targetSdkVersion* and *compilesdkversion* from *29* to *28* or any other lower level.

Comment: How is this a solution - not to target the latest API? Please consider suggesting how to implement this correctly in API 29.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>`

instead of

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/>"`

Some of your third party libraries are override `maxSdkVersion` like `com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android`, to finding them just check the `Merged Manifest` below of your manifest screen. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709872/2652368)

**For SDK 29 and Later**

If you are still having issue to accessing external storage, consider using `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your `<application>` tag of your manifest.

Comment: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` this fixed my issue in android 9 thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just a notice: on Android P I had to show a terminate dialog box to user asking to restart the app because even after all written above app couldn't read external storage, only after restart. Seriously, those guys in google makes Android better each time. 6, 8, and now so much troubles with 9, one more such stupid update and I will go to iOS :)