# API 26+: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is always denied

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I have switched my app to target API 27 and now it can't be granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission -- `grantResult` is always `-1`.

My app needs this permission since it doesn't use apps private external storage space (which [doesn't require](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` starting from API 19).

I know that in API 26 there have been [behavior changes for permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#rmp). However this doesn't explain my problem.

I'm requesting both `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in a standard way:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }, requestCode);
```

(both permissions are declared via `<uses-permission` in manifest).

The dialog appears and I click "Allow":

[image]

However inside `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback I'm getting a `-1`(denied) for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (and `0` (granted) for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

Shouldn't the result be `0` for both since I have requested and, presumably, granted both?

I have tried to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` alone, but in this case the dialog doesn't appear at all.

One more detail: I have just checked the merged manifest in `build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug` and noticed that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has attribute `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` (there is no such attribute in my manifest). This could be happening because my app has `minApiVersion=21`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "both permissions are declared via <uses-permission in manifest" -- are you certain? Your symptoms match what I would expect if `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was not requested in the manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, both are in the manifest. However, I have just checked the merged manifest in `build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug` and noticed that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has attribute `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` (there is no such attribute in my manifest). Can this be causing the issue?

Comment: Ah, that could be the problem. Presumably, some library has that, and it is getting merged in. Try adding `tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"` on your `<uses-permission>` element, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I believe read/write belong to the same permissiongroup and thus only one of them needs to be granted. But I might remember wrong on that.

Comment: @Ch4t4r: They changed that behavior in 8.0 -- even though they are in the same permission group, you still need to request runtime permissions for both of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare it worked! Probably manifest merger has been adding `maxSdkVersion=18` because my `minSdkVersion` is `21`. This feels counterintuitive and is worth filing a bug to google. I have updated the question with the information about the merged manifest. If you post your suggestion as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it is working. I'll make a point to blog about this next week.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, you are picking up that `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` attribute. My guess is that it is coming from a library. Check the "Merged Manifest" tab in Android Studio, when you are editing your own manifest. It will have details of what is contributing the various elements and attributes.

`android:maxSdkVersion` has the effect of removing your `<uses-permission>` element on higher Android SDK versions, at least in terms of how runtime permissions work.

Since you need this permission for all versions, adding `tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"` on the `<uses-permission>` element should revert the `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` and give you what you expect.

Comment: Never noticed there's actually a "Merged Manifest" tab in Android Studio, that's really nice.

Comment: Had 100% exact problem as @DenisKniazhev but this solution worked!
I also didn't know there's something like "Merged Manifest".
For those like me, the "Merged Manifest" tab can be found when you open your "AndroidManifest.xml" file right beside the "Text" tab, which is located at the bottom left (for Android Studio 3.1.3) of your Manifest file.

Comment: What is the solution??

Comment: If you're using HockeyApp and you're unable to write to external storage, this is why. You can also do `tools:node="replace"`

Comment: `HockeyApp ` make me happy

Comment: Re:HockeyApp -- interesting -- another Microsoft acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a space in my permission in manifest, it was `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE "/>` and I changed it to `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and problem solved.