# How to have Read + Write external storage after targeting android O (26) 8.0

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

Before targetting android O code below worked perfectly. After setting targetApi=27 (8.1) this stopped working.

```
context.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        requestCode);
```

I am presented with a permission dialog we all know, I gladly allow App to access photos media and files on a device.

and in `onRequestPermissionResult()` it returns

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE == 0, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE == -1
```

I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353465/4858147 didn't work.

While I was looking for a solution, found this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#rmp I wasn't cleverer after reading this, but I am 100% sure this is causing it.

> If the app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system grants only
>   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that time; however, if the app later requests
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the system immediately grants that privilege
>   without prompting the user.

I tried asking only for read permission (*dialog-> allow*) and later I asked for write permission (*no dialog -> still not granted*) it didn't work.

manifest:

```
<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- I added now, -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<!-- Storage Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Account Access Permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Vibrate used for notification updates -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I need permission for this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra("output", outputDestination);
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: @kdblue I get no visible error as I am not granted WRITE permission and my app doesn't continue in that case. If I had WRITE i would I call  camera in IMAGE_CAPTURE and I pass output as location where to store

Comment: @svkaka are you requesting camera permission?

Comment: you don't need camera permission for IMAGE_CAPTURE @Sagar

Comment: @svkaka i think you forget to take camera permission ?

Comment: @Sagar I can try :) but I don't think this is what is causing it

Comment: @kdblue it's not required

Comment: @svkaka It would be helpful if you could update your question with all the permissions requested.

Comment: @TimCastelijns why ?

Comment: @Sagar i added it but the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I fixed it :) thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I finally know what's happening, after reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709872/4858147 I was finally able to continue.

Problem was that HockeyApp had in manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

and after manifests were merged there was no WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in app. The app worked before thanks to a bug in an android system

> Prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26), if an app requested a permission
>   at runtime and the permission was granted, the system also incorrectly
>   granted the app the rest of the permissions that belonged to the same
>   permission group, and that were registered in the manifest.

It worked before thanks to  bug in Android system, because we asked for read permission

All I did was that in my main App manifest I changed

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

and add

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to Application