# Can't save bitmap images in my gallery

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment that displays a camera and, when the user clicks the main button, one photo is taken. I tried to create a path in the gallery and save images there but every time I open the gallery in my emulator, there is no folder with the images. Do you know what may be causing this problem? This is the code I have:

**Code to create the path and save images**

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {

   final String appDirectoryName = "/Feel/";
   String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + appDirectoryName;
     File myDir = new File(root);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image-" + image_name + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    Log.i("LOAD", root + fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save bitmap to android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624756/how-to-save-bitmap-to-android-gallery)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman ahah i saw this code from there

Comment: and I still can't make it so... no duplicate

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: @MuhammadUsman https://pastebin.com/hWRD23y6 here

Comment: What Android OS version are you running?

Comment: It says in emulator it's Android 7.1.1

Comment: I do believe you still need to write the contents of the Output Stream to disk. compress() does not do that for you - it merely compresses the contents to the stream which still needs to be written.

Comment: @CmosBattery Can you be a little more specific? I don't understand much about this FILE's methods ahah

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files <- this is just easier than duplicating everything in a comment or even an answer =)

Take note of outputStream.write()

Comment: Actually, I've read that. I just couldn't understand the write the files of the Output Stream to disk. I mean, I made everything that the question that is linked to this had and I still couldn't create. I have all permissions

Comment: For one you're not using the write() method =)

Comment: @CmosBattery Ohh, that was easier ahah I got you! I need to add out.write() but what do I add inside that method?

Comment: I could be wrong... going to try myself right now...

Comment: @CmosBattery Ok. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: never mind compress() does actually also write the stream to file too. So l will look for something else...

Comment: @CmosBattery Yeah, in this meanwhile I've read that compress does create the file too. I'm still trying to resolve this too ;)

Comment: Its funny, I have one app that writes to /download and right now I can't figure out what's different lol

Comment: Oh, I think that's what it is, you need to use the paths properly such as new file = File(newLocalPath, queuedFileName) such as you had then FileOutputStream(file) BUT you also need to check permissions from code too. The app that I was testing in is using app cache so I don't have them set up here. Without that you will get permission denied. And with paths incorrect you will get file not found or whatever error (which I think was happening when I first ran your code). https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: So, you're saying that I need to set permissions on run time and change  my `File file = new File(putHereMyRoot, putHereMyFile)`??

Comment: @CmosBattery I found the problem. While debugging I found out that it can't compile these lines `finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);` I don't know why, but it goes redirected to the "catch". What may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {
     try {

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", image_name);
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

and don't forget to add the permission to write and read from the external storage
see this for more details 
[Permission denied on writing to external storage despite permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44455887/6118808)

Comment: don't forget to check if the image is in JPG format or not